# Use while loop to print series of even and odd numbers

Tags: c++

I know I'm missing something real simple but I can't seem to get the numbers to print out in rows of just odd or just even numbers using a while loop or loops. Also It keeps printing out "the even numbers are:"/ "the odd numbers are:" for every number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    //declare variables
    int number;
    int n;

    cout << "Enter value less than 100: ";
    cin >> n; //take user input


    while (n <= 100) //loop only if n equals 100 or less
    {
        for(number = n; number <= n; number++) //for loop to increment int value
        {
            if(number % 2 !=0) //determines if odd
            {
                cout << "The odd numbers are:" <<number << endl; //prints odd values
            }
        }

        for(number = n;number <= n; number++) // for loop to increment int value
        {
            if(number % 2 ==0) //determines if even 
            {
                cout <<"The even numbers are:" <<number <<endl; //prints even values
            }
        }

        n++;
    }

    return 0; //end of program
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //declare variables
    int number;
    int n;

    cout << "Enter value less than 100: ";
    cin >> n; //take user input

    // print odd values
    cout << "The odd numbers are:";
    for (number = n + 1 - (n % 2); number <= 100; number += 2)
    {
        cout << " " << number;
    }
    cout << endl;

    // print even values
    cout << "The even numbers are:";
    for (number = n + (n % 2); number <= 100; number += 2)
    {
        cout << " " << number;
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0; //end of program
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is for an assignment  and we have to use a while loop or loops.

Comment: There are no variable declarations in initialize part of these `for` loops, so you can convert them to `while` loop by replacing `for(initialization; condition; proceed) {statements;}` with `initialization; while(condition) {statements; proceed;}`